# How to copy B1 down to the last columns in the data set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to drag the columns down from `B1` to the last row in the dataset. `B1` will always be populated with value and I need this to be copied and pasted 'x' amount of times down column `B` depending on how many rows there are on the sheet.

```
Sub Button1test_Click()

Set src = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

src.Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Value = "B1"

End Sub
```

columns `B` should be populated with 'lucord' x amount of times.

Comment: Still doesnt populate the other cells in the columns, i have 10 rows in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"B1"` is the text "B1" and not the reference to the range `B1`.

Also this is a great use case for a `With...End With` block to qualify the `Range` calls - otherwise `Lastrow` is determined from the active sheet, which may not necessarily be `src`.

Change

```
Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

src.Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Value = "B1"
```

to

```
With src
    Lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Value = .Range("B1").Value
End With
```

**EDIT:** If only `B1` is populated, then `Lastrow` = `1`. Determine `Lastrow` based on a populated column, e.g. Column A:

```
Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, thats makes more sense but my column isnt being populated. I have 'lucord' in b1 and need it coped it and pasted to the last row.

Comment: No repro. What is the last row number? Should you be getting the last row based on another column and not column B? If only B1 is populated, then `LastRow` = `1`. If it's column A, change to `LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`